# My own created function: RemoveNA runs half

Tags: r

Here is my code :

```
    PATH <- 
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thomaspernet/data_csv_r/master/data/titanic_csv.csv"

df_titanic <- read.csv(PATH, sep = ",")

RemoveNA = 
function(x)
{
  colmiss = colnames(x)[apply(x,2,anyNA)]
  colmiss
  i = 1
  while ( i <= length(colmiss))
  {
   col_na_col  = match(colsmiss[i],names(x))
   col_na_col 
   for (n in col_na_col)
   {
    #column_name = colsmiss[i]
    cat('  Your missing column is: ' ,'"',colsmiss[i],'"','  and col.no is : ',n, '||||')
    # Create mean
    average_missing <- mean(x[,colsmiss[i]],na.rm =TRUE)
    average_missing
    x[n][is.na(x[n])] = average_missing
   }
   i = i + 1
  }
} 

sum(is.na(df_titanic))
RemoveNA(df_titanic)
```

When I run the function ***RemoveNA***, it gives :
Your missing column is:  **" age "   and col.no is :  6 ||||  Your missing column is:  " fare "   and col.no is :  10 ||||**
which is okay, but the *replacement below is not done properly*, as sum(is.na(df_titanic)) both before and after sums upto 264

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more straightforward way :

```
df1 <- data.frame(a= c(NA,1,NA,2), b = 1:4)
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)))
df1
#     a b
# 1 1.5 1
# 2 1.0 2
# 3 1.5 3
# 4 2.0 4
```

Your code has a type, you typed `colsmiss` instead of `colmiss`.

Also your code doesn't return anything (well it returns the last value of I), so your transformation of the NA values is not recorded anywhere.

Your corrected function :

```
RemoveNA = function(x)
  {
    colmiss = colnames(x)[apply(x,2,anyNA)]
    colmiss
    i = 1
    while ( i <= length(colmiss))
    {
      col_na_col  = match(colmiss[i],names(x))
      col_na_col 
      for (n in col_na_col)
      {
        #column_name = colsmiss[i]
        cat('  Your missing column is: ' ,'"',colmiss[i],'"','  and col.no is : ',n, '||||')
        # Create mean
        average_missing <- mean(x[,colmiss[i]],na.rm =TRUE)
        average_missing
        x[n][is.na(x[n])] = average_missing
      }
      i = i + 1
    }
    x
  }
```